# Why are Vincent's and Spike's souls similar?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In Cowboy Bebop, after the battle on the monorail, Spike is thrown off and almost dies. When he revives he says that Vincent and him have similar souls and that he must confront him.

Why is this so? What qualities do Vincent and Spike share for him to say such a statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that they are both broken people.  Though they way they choose to publically act is very different, which makes them seem superficially very different, they both hide their regrets and broken personalities behind false exteriors.